# Changing A label text without PostBack (using Update Panels)

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

i created an ASP.NET Website. 
What i want to do is to make a label change its content depending on the item selected by a drop down list.
I tried this but it didn't work:

The Drop down list looks like this:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDown1" runat="server" >
    <asp:ListItem Value="a"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="b"></asp:ListItem>
    onselectedindexchanged="DropDown1_SelectedIndexChanged"
</asp:DropDownList>
```

the label:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" Text="" runat="server"/>
```

I want to do it without having to use **PostBack**.

I tried to use ajax **Update panel** Like this:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" id="UpdatePanel" updatemode="Conditional">        
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger controlid="DropDown1"                                       EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" Text="" runat="server"/>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And in the **DropDown1_SelectedIndexChanged** Event in the **code behind**:

```
protected void DropDown1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = DropDown1.SelectedValue;
}
```

But this is not working.

Can anyone Help me with it?

Thank you very much for any help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is your solution..

replace your dropdown aspx control with below one..

```
  <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDown1" runat="server" onselectedindexchanged="DropDown1_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
                <asp:ListItem Value="a"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="b"></asp:ListItem>
           </asp:DropDownList>

<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" id="UpdatePanel" updatemode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" Text="test" runat="server"/>
    </ContentTemplate>

    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger controlid="DropDown1" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Please, Check this code... With replacing your code. in aspx page only. your code behind is right...

Comment: So although only the content in the UpdatePanel is rendered again, the entire page data is sent to the server even on partial postback?

Comment: Yes, Page load method called again. but We will put  if(!Page.ispostback) method there.

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't know thought that AutoPostBack="true" will do a full post back. but apparently not

Answer (score 5):

You need to enable autopostback and put the event handler definition in the right place:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDown1" runat="server" onselectedindexchanged="DropDown1_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
                                <asp:ListItem Value="a"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="b"></asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: That you for your answer. it worked. unfortunatly i cannot accept 2 answers

Answer (score 0):

http://encosia.com/why-aspnet-ajax-updatepanels-are-dangerous/

Read that article about, why NOT use updatepanels, there is alot of other much better solutions for doing the job.

Comment: this is interesting. But other solutions involve using javascript (Something that I never used) I might check it out when I have free time

Comment: The linked site appears to have been hacked.